# dpkg was interrupted

Tags: dpkg

I got an error while trying to install phpmyadmin on my Raspberry Pi 3,
the error message is:

> dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'

I think it's a problem related to the `/var/lib` folder, something went wrong and files got corrupted.

After running the command `sudo dpkg -- etc...` it seems everything is fine but when I try to install the package of phpmyadmin again, another error message appeared:

> Error bus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all the files inside `/var/lib/dpkg/updates` directory with the following commands:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

And then run this command to get the newer ones:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Did you mean `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: After a long run I found this answer. You saved my time and effort boss. I have been encountering this problem in my Raspberry Pi OS frequently !